# Numpy: Transform list into square array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, reshape

I have a list `t` with a square number of elements, e.g. 16, 25, 400.
Now want to create a numpy array `a` full of zeros with the same size but in a square shape, e.g. 4x4, 5x5, 20x20.

I found a solution:

```
a = np.zeros(2 * (int(np.sqrt(len(t))),))
```

or

```
a = np.zeros(len(t)).reshape(int(np.sqrt(len(t))), int(np.sqrt(len(t))))
```

It is working, but it is very ugly and I am sure there must be a better way to do this.
Something like `a = np.zeros(t, 2)`.
Any idea for that?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Your first suggestion is the shortest you can make it. If it's unreadable, extract a `square_shape(length)` function, and use `np.zeros(square_shape(len(l)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
shp = int(np.sqrt(len(l))
a = np.zeros((shp, shp))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean it up like so:

```
size = len(l)
sqrt = int(np.sqrt(size))
a = np.zeros((sqrt, sqrt))
```

Any time you are writing the same fragment of code multiple times, it is good to replace with a variable, function etc.

Comment: This is what i tried in the first attempt. But it is so bad readable. And so many variables for such a small task, I also do not like^^